# PHP - failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, file-upload

I am having trouble uploading files to my website.

the code:

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];
  //filepath
  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){

    //Setup the new file path
    $newFilePath = "./uploads/$keuze/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    //Upload the file into the temp dir
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

       //unfinished

    }
```

this worked perfect with xampp, but now that the website is online, i get the following error: 
Warning: move_uploaded_file(./uploads/barbeque 2012/endless.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/arnoudi26/domains/creemersa.be/public_html/upload.php on line 36

I have set the permissions to read/write to the whole map and still not working.

Comment: Using `$_FILES['upload']['name']` name to store file is not a good idea. someone can spoof it.

Comment: Have you tried `is_writable($newFilePath)`?

Comment: yes, it is set to CHMOD 777

Comment: What is the output for ls -al //home/arnoudi26/domains/creemersa.be/public_html/uploads

Comment: I found it... Stupid me, I had only set the 'uploads' directory to CHMOD 777, not the subdirectories... What should I use instead of $_FILES['upload']['name']? Thanks!